# Complete list of layout classes in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to know if there is an already made list of Bootstrap classes... there are many classes not referenced in the docs...

Otherway I will have to look into CSS and make my own list, which would take much time!

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

- I found one resource in github https://gist.github.com/Integralist/1391440
- Even if it's not a complete set of css classes list that you are expecting, you can contribute or start contributing one like this to others to help them in this way

Answer (score 3):

[Base CSS Examples](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.0.4/docs/base-css.html) for a complete list of CSS layout classes with preview. I use this.

Answer (score 2):

I've made such list of Bootstrap 3 CSS classes with a simple description, it might help you.

[List of Bootstrap 3 CSS classes with description](http://tomasjanecek.cz/en/clanky/post/list-of-bootstrap-3-css-classes-with-description)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of **all Bootstrap 4 classes** as of 1/19/2018

You can find a sortable list of these classes, image preview, description, and link to documentation [here](https://bootstrapcreative.com/resources/bootstrap-4-css-classes-index/)

```
.active
.alert
.alert-danger
.alert-dark
.alert-dismissible
.alert-heading
.alert-info
.alert-light
.alert-link
.alert-primary
.alert-secondary
.alert-success
.alert-warning
.align-baseline
.align-bottom
.align-content-around
.align-content-between
.align-content-center
.align-content-end
.align-content-lg-around
.align-content-lg-between
.align-content-lg-center
.align-content-lg-end
.align-content-lg-start
.align-content-lg-stretch
.align-content-md-around
.align-content-md-between
.align-content-md-center
.align-content-md-end
.align-content-md-start
.align-content-md-stretch
.align-content-sm-around
.align-content-sm-between
.align-content-sm-center
.align-content-sm-end
.align-content-sm-start
.align-content-sm-stretch
.align-content-start
.align-content-stretch
.align-content-xl-around
.align-content-xl-between
.align-content-xl-center
.align-content-xl-end
.align-content-xl-start
.align-content-xl-stretch
.align-items-baseline
.align-items-center
.align-items-end
.align-items-lg-baseline
.align-items-lg-center
.align-items-lg-end
.align-items-lg-start
.align-items-lg-stretch
.align-items-md-baseline
.align-items-md-center
.align-items-md-end
.align-items-md-start
.align-items-md-stretch
.align-items-sm-baseline
.align-items-sm-center
.align-items-sm-end
.align-items-sm-start
.align-items-sm-stretch
.align-items-start
.align-items-stretch
.align-items-xl-baseline
.align-items-xl-center
.align-items-xl-end
.align-items-xl-start
.align-items-xl-stretch
.align-middle
.align-self-auto
.align-self-baseline
.align-self-center
.align-self-end
.align-self-lg-auto
.align-self-lg-baseline
.align-self-lg-center
.align-self-lg-end
.align-self-lg-start
.align-self-lg-stretch
.align-self-md-auto
.align-self-md-baseline
.align-self-md-center
.align-self-md-end
.align-self-md-start
.align-self-md-stretch
.align-self-sm-auto
.align-self-sm-baseline
.align-self-sm-center
.align-self-sm-end
.align-self-sm-start
.align-self-sm-stretch
.align-self-start
.align-self-stretch
.align-self-xl-auto
.align-self-xl-baseline
.align-self-xl-center
.align-self-xl-end
.align-self-xl-start
.align-self-xl-stretch
.align-text-bottom
.align-text-top
.align-top
.arrow
.badge
.badge-danger
.badge-dark
.badge-info
.badge-light
.badge-pill
.badge-primary
.badge-secondary
.badge-success
.badge-warning
.bg-danger
.bg-dark
.bg-info
.bg-light
.bg-primary
.bg-secondary
.bg-success
.bg-transparent
.bg-warning
.bg-white
.blockquote
.blockquote-footer
.border
.border-0
.border-bottom-0
.border-danger
.border-dark
.border-info
.border-left-0
.border-light
.border-primary
.border-right-0
.border-secondary
.border-success
.border-top-0
.border-warning
.border-white
.breadcrumb
.breadcrumb-item
.bs-popover-auto
.bs-popover-bottom
.bs-popover-left
.bs-popover-right
.bs-popover-top
.bs-tooltip-auto
.bs-tooltip-bottom
.bs-tooltip-left
.bs-tooltip-right
.bs-tooltip-top
.btn
.btn-block
.btn-danger
.btn-dark
.btn-group
.btn-group-lg
.btn-group-sm
.btn-group-toggle
.btn-group-vertical
.btn-info
.btn-lg
.btn-light
.btn-link
.btn-outline-danger
.btn-outline-dark
.btn-outline-info
.btn-outline-light
.btn-outline-primary
.btn-outline-secondary
.btn-outline-success
.btn-outline-warning
.btn-primary
.btn-secondary
.btn-sm
.btn-success
.btn-toolbar
.btn-warning
.card
.card-body
.card-columns
.card-deck
.card-footer
.card-group
.card-header
.card-header-pills
.card-header-tabs
.card-img
.card-img-bottom
.card-img-overlay
.card-img-top
.card-link
.card-subtitle
.card-text
.card-title
.carousel
.carousel-caption
.carousel-control-next
.carousel-control-next-icon
.carousel-control-prev
.carousel-control-prev-icon
.carousel-indicators
.carousel-inner
.carousel-item
.carousel-item-left
.carousel-item-next
.carousel-item-prev
.carousel-item-right
.clearfix
.close
.col
.col-1
.col-10
.col-11
.col-12
.col-2
.col-3
.col-4
.col-5
.col-6
.col-7
.col-8
.col-9
.col-auto
.col-form-label
.col-form-label-lg
.col-form-label-sm
.col-lg
.col-lg-1
.col-lg-10
.col-lg-11
.col-lg-12
.col-lg-2
.col-lg-3
.col-lg-4
.col-lg-5
.col-lg-6
.col-lg-7
.col-lg-8
.col-lg-9
.col-lg-auto
.col-md
.col-md-1
.col-md-10
.col-md-11
.col-md-12
.col-md-2
.col-md-3
.col-md-4
.col-md-5
.col-md-6
.col-md-7
.col-md-8
.col-md-9
.col-md-auto
.col-sm
.col-sm-1
.col-sm-10
.col-sm-11
.col-sm-12
.col-sm-2
.col-sm-3
.col-sm-4
.col-sm-5
.col-sm-6
.col-sm-7
.col-sm-8
.col-sm-9
.col-sm-auto
.col-xl
.col-xl-1
.col-xl-10
.col-xl-11
.col-xl-12
.col-xl-2
.col-xl-3
.col-xl-4
.col-xl-5
.col-xl-6
.col-xl-7
.col-xl-8
.col-xl-9
.col-xl-auto
.collapse
.collapsing
.container
.container-fluid
.custom-checkbox
.custom-control
.custom-control-inline
.custom-control-input
.custom-control-label
.custom-file
.custom-file-control
.custom-file-input
.custom-file-label
.custom-radio
.custom-select
.custom-select-lg
.custom-select-sm
.d-block
.d-flex
.d-inline
.d-inline-block
.d-inline-flex
.d-lg-block
.d-lg-flex
.d-lg-inline
.d-lg-inline-block
.d-lg-inline-flex
.d-lg-none
.d-lg-table
.d-lg-table-cell
.d-lg-table-row
.d-md-block
.d-md-flex
.d-md-inline
.d-md-inline-block
.d-md-inline-flex
.d-md-none
.d-md-table
.d-md-table-cell
.d-md-table-row
.d-none
.d-print-block
.d-print-inline
.d-print-inline-block
.d-print-none
.d-sm-block
.d-sm-flex
.d-sm-inline
.d-sm-inline-block
.d-sm-inline-flex
.d-sm-none
.d-sm-table
.d-sm-table-cell
.d-sm-table-row
.d-table
.d-table-cell
.d-table-row
.d-xl-block
.d-xl-flex
.d-xl-inline
.d-xl-inline-block
.d-xl-inline-flex
.d-xl-none
.d-xl-table
.d-xl-table-cell
.d-xl-table-row
.disabled
.display-1
.display-2
.display-3
.display-4
.dropdown
.dropdown-divider
.dropdown-header
.dropdown-item
.dropdown-menu
.dropdown-menu-right
.dropdown-toggle
.dropdown-toggle-split
.dropleft
.dropright
.dropup
.embed-responsive
.embed-responsive-16by9
.embed-responsive-1by1
.embed-responsive-21by9
.embed-responsive-4by3
.embed-responsive-item
.fade
.figure
.figure-caption
.figure-img
.fixed-bottom
.fixed-top
.flex-column
.flex-column-reverse
.flex-lg-column
.flex-lg-column-reverse
.flex-lg-nowrap
.flex-lg-row
.flex-lg-row-reverse
.flex-lg-wrap
.flex-lg-wrap-reverse
.flex-md-column
.flex-md-column-reverse
.flex-md-nowrap
.flex-md-row
.flex-md-row-reverse
.flex-md-wrap
.flex-md-wrap-reverse
.flex-nowrap
.flex-row
.flex-row-reverse
.flex-sm-column
.flex-sm-column-reverse
.flex-sm-nowrap
.flex-sm-row
.flex-sm-row-reverse
.flex-sm-wrap
.flex-sm-wrap-reverse
.flex-wrap
.flex-wrap-reverse
.flex-xl-column
.flex-xl-column-reverse
.flex-xl-nowrap
.flex-xl-row
.flex-xl-row-reverse
.flex-xl-wrap
.flex-xl-wrap-reverse
.float-left
.float-lg-left
.float-lg-none
.float-lg-right
.float-md-left
.float-md-none
.float-md-right
.float-none
.float-right
.float-sm-left
.float-sm-none
.float-sm-right
.float-xl-left
.float-xl-none
.float-xl-right
.focus
.font-italic
.font-weight-bold
.font-weight-light
.font-weight-normal
.form-check
.form-check-inline
.form-check-input
.form-check-label
.form-control
.form-control-file
.form-control-lg
.form-control-plaintext
.form-control-range
.form-control-sm
.form-group
.form-inline
.form-row
.form-text
.h-100
.h-25
.h-50
.h-75
.h1
.h2
.h3
.h4
.h5
.h6
.img-fluid
.img-thumbnail
.initialism
.input-group
.input-group-append
.input-group-lg
.input-group-prepend
.input-group-sm
.input-group-text
.invalid-feedback
.invalid-tooltip
.invisible
.is-invalid
.is-valid
.jumbotron
.jumbotron-fluid
.justify-content-around
.justify-content-between
.justify-content-center
.justify-content-end
.justify-content-lg-around
.justify-content-lg-between
.justify-content-lg-center
.justify-content-lg-end
.justify-content-lg-start
.justify-content-md-around
.justify-content-md-between
.justify-content-md-center
.justify-content-md-end
.justify-content-md-start
.justify-content-sm-around
.justify-content-sm-between
.justify-content-sm-center
.justify-content-sm-end
.justify-content-sm-start
.justify-content-start
.justify-content-xl-around
.justify-content-xl-between
.justify-content-xl-center
.justify-content-xl-end
.justify-content-xl-start
.lead
.list-group
.list-group-flush
.list-group-item
.list-group-item-action
.list-group-item-danger
.list-group-item-dark
.list-group-item-info
.list-group-item-light
.list-group-item-primary
.list-group-item-secondary
.list-group-item-success
.list-group-item-warning
.list-inline
.list-inline-item
.list-unstyled
.m-0
.m-1
.m-2
.m-3
.m-4
.m-5
.m-auto
.m-lg-0
.m-lg-1
.m-lg-2
.m-lg-3
.m-lg-4
.m-lg-5
.m-lg-auto
.m-md-0
.m-md-1
.m-md-2
.m-md-3
.m-md-4
.m-md-5
.m-md-auto
.m-sm-0
.m-sm-1
.m-sm-2
.m-sm-3
.m-sm-4
.m-sm-5
.m-sm-auto
.m-xl-0
.m-xl-1
.m-xl-2
.m-xl-3
.m-xl-4
.m-xl-5
.m-xl-auto
.mark
.mb-0
.mb-1
.mb-2
.mb-3
.mb-4
.mb-5
.mb-auto
.mb-lg-0
.mb-lg-1
.mb-lg-2
.mb-lg-3
.mb-lg-4
.mb-lg-5
.mb-lg-auto
.mb-md-0
.mb-md-1
.mb-md-2
.mb-md-3
.mb-md-4
.mb-md-5
.mb-md-auto
.mb-sm-0
.mb-sm-1
.mb-sm-2
.mb-sm-3
.mb-sm-4
.mb-sm-5
.mb-sm-auto
.mb-xl-0
.mb-xl-1
.mb-xl-2
.mb-xl-3
.mb-xl-4
.mb-xl-5
.mb-xl-auto
.media
.media-body
.mh-100
.ml-0
.ml-1
.ml-2
.ml-3
.ml-4
.ml-5
.ml-auto
.ml-lg-0
.ml-lg-1
.ml-lg-2
.ml-lg-3
.ml-lg-4
.ml-lg-5
.ml-lg-auto
.ml-md-0
.ml-md-1
.ml-md-2
.ml-md-3
.ml-md-4
.ml-md-5
.ml-md-auto
.ml-sm-0
.ml-sm-1
.ml-sm-2
.ml-sm-3
.ml-sm-4
.ml-sm-5
.ml-sm-auto
.ml-xl-0
.ml-xl-1
.ml-xl-2
.ml-xl-3
.ml-xl-4
.ml-xl-5
.ml-xl-auto
.modal
.modal-backdrop
.modal-body
.modal-content
.modal-dialog
.modal-dialog-centered
.modal-footer
.modal-header
.modal-lg
.modal-open
.modal-scrollbar-measure
.modal-sm
.modal-title
.mr-0
.mr-1
.mr-2
.mr-3
.mr-4
.mr-5
.mr-auto
.mr-lg-0
.mr-lg-1
.mr-lg-2
.mr-lg-3
.mr-lg-4
.mr-lg-5
.mr-lg-auto
.mr-md-0
.mr-md-1
.mr-md-2
.mr-md-3
.mr-md-4
.mr-md-5
.mr-md-auto
.mr-sm-0
.mr-sm-1
.mr-sm-2
.mr-sm-3
.mr-sm-4
.mr-sm-5
.mr-sm-auto
.mr-xl-0
.mr-xl-1
.mr-xl-2
.mr-xl-3
.mr-xl-4
.mr-xl-5
.mr-xl-auto
.mt-0
.mt-1
.mt-2
.mt-3
.mt-4
.mt-5
.mt-auto
.mt-lg-0
.mt-lg-1
.mt-lg-2
.mt-lg-3
.mt-lg-4
.mt-lg-5
.mt-lg-auto
.mt-md-0
.mt-md-1
.mt-md-2
.mt-md-3
.mt-md-4
.mt-md-5
.mt-md-auto
.mt-sm-0
.mt-sm-1
.mt-sm-2
.mt-sm-3
.mt-sm-4
.mt-sm-5
.mt-sm-auto
.mt-xl-0
.mt-xl-1
.mt-xl-2
.mt-xl-3
.mt-xl-4
.mt-xl-5
.mt-xl-auto
.mw-100
.mx-0
.mx-1
.mx-2
.mx-3
.mx-4
.mx-5
.mx-auto
.mx-lg-0
.mx-lg-1
.mx-lg-2
.mx-lg-3
.mx-lg-4
.mx-lg-5
.mx-lg-auto
.mx-md-0
.mx-md-1
.mx-md-2
.mx-md-3
.mx-md-4
.mx-md-5
.mx-md-auto
.mx-sm-0
.mx-sm-1
.mx-sm-2
.mx-sm-3
.mx-sm-4
.mx-sm-5
.mx-sm-auto
.mx-xl-0
.mx-xl-1
.mx-xl-2
.mx-xl-3
.mx-xl-4
.mx-xl-5
.mx-xl-auto
.my-0
.my-1
.my-2
.my-3
.my-4
.my-5
.my-auto
.my-lg-0
.my-lg-1
.my-lg-2
.my-lg-3
.my-lg-4
.my-lg-5
.my-lg-auto
.my-md-0
.my-md-1
.my-md-2
.my-md-3
.my-md-4
.my-md-5
.my-md-auto
.my-sm-0
.my-sm-1
.my-sm-2
.my-sm-3
.my-sm-4
.my-sm-5
.my-sm-auto
.my-xl-0
.my-xl-1
.my-xl-2
.my-xl-3
.my-xl-4
.my-xl-5
.my-xl-auto
.nav
.nav-fill
.nav-item
.nav-justified
.nav-link
.nav-pills
.nav-tabs
.navbar
.navbar-brand
.navbar-collapse
.navbar-dark
.navbar-expand
.navbar-expand-lg
.navbar-expand-md
.navbar-expand-sm
.navbar-expand-xl
.navbar-light
.navbar-nav
.navbar-text
.navbar-toggler
.navbar-toggler-icon
.no-gutters
.offset-1
.offset-10
.offset-11
.offset-2
.offset-3
.offset-4
.offset-5
.offset-6
.offset-7
.offset-8
.offset-9
.offset-lg-0
.offset-lg-1
.offset-lg-10
.offset-lg-11
.offset-lg-2
.offset-lg-3
.offset-lg-4
.offset-lg-5
.offset-lg-6
.offset-lg-7
.offset-lg-8
.offset-lg-9
.offset-md-0
.offset-md-1
.offset-md-10
.offset-md-11
.offset-md-2
.offset-md-3
.offset-md-4
.offset-md-5
.offset-md-6
.offset-md-7
.offset-md-8
.offset-md-9
.offset-sm-0
.offset-sm-1
.offset-sm-10
.offset-sm-11
.offset-sm-2
.offset-sm-3
.offset-sm-4
.offset-sm-5
.offset-sm-6
.offset-sm-7
.offset-sm-8
.offset-sm-9
.offset-xl-0
.offset-xl-1
.offset-xl-10
.offset-xl-11
.offset-xl-2
.offset-xl-3
.offset-xl-4
.offset-xl-5
.offset-xl-6
.offset-xl-7
.offset-xl-8
.offset-xl-9
.order-1
.order-10
.order-11
.order-12
.order-2
.order-3
.order-4
.order-5
.order-6
.order-7
.order-8
.order-9
.order-first
.order-lg-1
.order-lg-10
.order-lg-11
.order-lg-12
.order-lg-2
.order-lg-3
.order-lg-4
.order-lg-5
.order-lg-6
.order-lg-7
.order-lg-8
.order-lg-9
.order-lg-first
.order-md-1
.order-md-10
.order-md-11
.order-md-12
.order-md-2
.order-md-3
.order-md-4
.order-md-5
.order-md-6
.order-md-7
.order-md-8
.order-md-9
.order-md-first
.order-sm-1
.order-sm-10
.order-sm-11
.order-sm-12
.order-sm-2
.order-sm-3
.order-sm-4
.order-sm-5
.order-sm-6
.order-sm-7
.order-sm-8
.order-sm-9
.order-sm-first
.order-xl-1
.order-xl-10
.order-xl-11
.order-xl-12
.order-xl-2
.order-xl-3
.order-xl-4
.order-xl-5
.order-xl-6
.order-xl-7
.order-xl-8
.order-xl-9
.order-xl-first
.p-0
.p-1
.p-2
.p-3
.p-4
.p-5
.p-lg-0
.p-lg-1
.p-lg-2
.p-lg-3
.p-lg-4
.p-lg-5
.p-md-0
.p-md-1
.p-md-2
.p-md-3
.p-md-4
.p-md-5
.p-sm-0
.p-sm-1
.p-sm-2
.p-sm-3
.p-sm-4
.p-sm-5
.p-xl-0
.p-xl-1
.p-xl-2
.p-xl-3
.p-xl-4
.p-xl-5
.page-item
.page-link
.pagination
.pagination-lg
.pagination-sm
.pb-0
.pb-1
.pb-2
.pb-3
.pb-4
.pb-5
.pb-lg-0
.pb-lg-1
.pb-lg-2
.pb-lg-3
.pb-lg-4
.pb-lg-5
.pb-md-0
.pb-md-1
.pb-md-2
.pb-md-3
.pb-md-4
.pb-md-5
.pb-sm-0
.pb-sm-1
.pb-sm-2
.pb-sm-3
.pb-sm-4
.pb-sm-5
.pb-xl-0
.pb-xl-1
.pb-xl-2
.pb-xl-3
.pb-xl-4
.pb-xl-5
.pl-0
.pl-1
.pl-2
.pl-3
.pl-4
.pl-5
.pl-lg-0
.pl-lg-1
.pl-lg-2
.pl-lg-3
.pl-lg-4
.pl-lg-5
.pl-md-0
.pl-md-1
.pl-md-2
.pl-md-3
.pl-md-4
.pl-md-5
.pl-sm-0
.pl-sm-1
.pl-sm-2
.pl-sm-3
.pl-sm-4
.pl-sm-5
.pl-xl-0
.pl-xl-1
.pl-xl-2
.pl-xl-3
.pl-xl-4
.pl-xl-5
.popover
.popover-body
.popover-header
.position-absolute
.position-fixed
.position-relative
.position-static
.position-sticky
.pr-0
.pr-1
.pr-2
.pr-3
.pr-4
.pr-5
.pr-lg-0
.pr-lg-1
.pr-lg-2
.pr-lg-3
.pr-lg-4
.pr-lg-5
.pr-md-0
.pr-md-1
.pr-md-2
.pr-md-3
.pr-md-4
.pr-md-5
.pr-sm-0
.pr-sm-1
.pr-sm-2
.pr-sm-3
.pr-sm-4
.pr-sm-5
.pr-xl-0
.pr-xl-1
.pr-xl-2
.pr-xl-3
.pr-xl-4
.pr-xl-5
.pre-scrollable
.progress
.progress-bar
.progress-bar-animated
.progress-bar-striped
.pt-0
.pt-1
.pt-2
.pt-3
.pt-4
.pt-5
.pt-lg-0
.pt-lg-1
.pt-lg-2
.pt-lg-3
.pt-lg-4
.pt-lg-5
.pt-md-0
.pt-md-1
.pt-md-2
.pt-md-3
.pt-md-4
.pt-md-5
.pt-sm-0
.pt-sm-1
.pt-sm-2
.pt-sm-3
.pt-sm-4
.pt-sm-5
.pt-xl-0
.pt-xl-1
.pt-xl-2
.pt-xl-3
.pt-xl-4
.pt-xl-5
.px-0
.px-1
.px-2
.px-3
.px-4
.px-5
.px-lg-0
.px-lg-1
.px-lg-2
.px-lg-3
.px-lg-4
.px-lg-5
.px-md-0
.px-md-1
.px-md-2
.px-md-3
.px-md-4
.px-md-5
.px-sm-0
.px-sm-1
.px-sm-2
.px-sm-3
.px-sm-4
.px-sm-5
.px-xl-0
.px-xl-1
.px-xl-2
.px-xl-3
.px-xl-4
.px-xl-5
.py-0
.py-1
.py-2
.py-3
.py-4
.py-5
.py-lg-0
.py-lg-1
.py-lg-2
.py-lg-3
.py-lg-4
.py-lg-5
.py-md-0
.py-md-1
.py-md-2
.py-md-3
.py-md-4
.py-md-5
.py-sm-0
.py-sm-1
.py-sm-2
.py-sm-3
.py-sm-4
.py-sm-5
.py-xl-0
.py-xl-1
.py-xl-2
.py-xl-3
.py-xl-4
.py-xl-5
.rounded
.rounded-0
.rounded-bottom
.rounded-circle
.rounded-left
.rounded-right
.rounded-top
.row
.show
.small
.sr-only
.sr-only-focusable
.tab-content
.tab-pane
.table
.table-active
.table-bordered
.table-danger
.table-dark
.table-hover
.table-info
.table-light
.table-primary
.table-responsive
.table-responsive-lg
.table-responsive-md
.table-responsive-sm
.table-responsive-xl
.table-secondary
.table-sm
.table-striped
.table-success
.table-warning
.text-capitalize
.text-center
.text-danger
.text-dark
.text-hide
.text-info
.text-justify
.text-left
.text-lg-center
.text-lg-left
.text-lg-right
.text-light
.text-lowercase
.text-md-center
.text-md-left
.text-md-right
.text-muted
.text-nowrap
.text-primary
.text-right
.text-secondary
.text-sm-center
.text-sm-left
.text-sm-right
.text-success
.text-truncate
.text-uppercase
.text-warning
.text-white
.text-xl-center
.text-xl-left
.text-xl-right
.thead-dark
.thead-light
.tooltip
.tooltip-inner
.valid-feedback
.valid-tooltip
.visible
.w-100
.w-25
.w-50
.w-75
.was-validated
```